npm testcontainers with Private container image registry
As we move to a Private container registry that requires authentication, the integration tests that use testcontainers library fail (403) becuase missing credentials.
The integration test is part of a ci/cd pipeline that runs in a GitHub Action runner. Both the runner and the docker in docker container can pull container images, but integration tests fails as the library is not picking up any of the existing credentials.
I fail to understand how things need to be configure so developers can run their integration tests. I would like to provide a solution that does not involve any credential to be store as text in GIT.
For that reason, I was exploring the possibility of either using:

docker build secrets
GitHub Actions secrets

But all my attempts end up nowhere, as it seems nothing works with that library.
Any suggestion on how to accomplish this?
